# how to set content-encoding metadata tags in gzip header files?

Tags: apache, webpack, compression, gzip, content-encoding

I am using webpack's compression plugin to gzip the content of files(html, js) and then I published gzip files removing the extension .gz to server(AWS/Nginx/Apache).

compression plugin of webpack's configuration:

```
new CompressionPlugin({   
  'asset': "[path]",
  'algorithm': "gzip",
  'test': /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
  'threshold': 10240,
  'minRatio': 0.8
})
```

I have tried AWS, Nginx and Apache. on AWS i have to set content-encoding metadata explicitly after uploading the files.

On Nginx there is a much simpler solution - http_gzip_static_module.

```
location / {
  gzip_static on;
  rewrite ^/?$ /index.html break;
  root /srv/app;
}
```

by setting gzip_static on to Nginx server it provides correct Content-Type and Content-Encoding being passed to the client.

So in both AWS and on Nginx it's working fine and I am trying to achieve the same thing on apache server but it results in unexpected token in gzip files.

After debugging, I got to understand the files which are gzipped does not have content-encoding: gzip as metadata tags and resulting browser's request to fail.

I want to understand if there is any way in webpack compression plugin or in webpack where we can explicitly add metadata of file? or anyother way I can handle this issue.

Comment: Trying to understand, when you say "metadata tag", are you referring to HTTP headers? Maybe this helps? https://knackforge.com/blog/karalmax/how-enable-gzip-compression-apache

Comment: @JimPerris i believe he don't need Apache deflate, instead he need solution on how to set for selected(or pattern matched) static files `Content-Encoding: gzip`.